# Passing Data from view to controller angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am passing a value through a function parameter in the view to the controller. Then i am storing that value in $scope. Then i am trying to access the same value through scope but in a different html page. But the value is not available. I am using UI-router for routing. Can anyone please tell what may be the cause for this?

this is the 1st page from which obj.roleId is being passed in the openwindow1 function to the controller.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table">
        <thead align="center" class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Role Name
                    <div class="getSortClass('roleName')"></div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    Role ID
                    <div class="getSortClass('roleID')"></div>
                </th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr align="center">
                <td>{{obj.roleName}}</td>
                <td>{{obj.roleID}}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Edit
                User</button><button class=
                "btn btn-primary">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and this the controller. i am storing the value in $scope.roleIdk:

```
.controller('UserRoleEdit', ['$compile', '$scope', '$window',
   function($compile, $scope, $window) {
       $scope.openWindow1 = function(roleID) {
           $window.open(
               'http://localhost:9000/#/homepage/userRoleEdit',
               'User Role
Edit',
               'width=1300,height=1000');
           $scope.roleIDk = roleID;
           alert($scope.roleIDk);
       };
   }
```

]);

Finally i am trying to access it in another html view:

## {{roleIDk}}

But i can't access it.

Comment: It's hard to help if we can't see your code :)

Comment: I have added the code. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sharing it between views the scope will be different, so whatever you add in a view scope wont be present in the other.

You can store it in a Service. Services are singleton so they will be shared in all your views.

You can also store it on the browser local storage.

In you scenario you may want to pass it as a parameter on the URL though:

```
$window.open('http://localhost:9000/#/homepage/userRoleEdit/' + roleID, User Role Edit', 'width=1300,height=1000');
```

You can then use the `$routeParams` service in the other view controller to access it.

Comment: its going to be used a lot of times. so how may values can i store? and how ill they be deleted once there is no use? Thank you for your help

Comment: Probably you want to use the URL for that. See my edit